# How to retrieve the selected value from Drop-downList using Onchange event in Perl?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Select tag in the form in which i am giving the Static Options,
My problem is to know "how to retrieve the value which i have selected",I dont want to use any Button to submit the value which i have selected.So i want to go with the "Onchange event " of select tag.

here's the code by which am populating the select tag:

```
 print qq[<td>Records PerPage</td>];
 print qq[<td><select name="'records'" size="1"><option value="2">2<option value="4"
   selected>4<option value="6">6<option value="10">10</select></td></tr>];
```

Please do help me Find the solution. Thank You

Comment: Perl doesn't have an `onChange` event, or any other DOM events for that matter. If you want to figure out the selected value without sending it back to the server side by submitting a form, you'll have to do it on the client-side, and are therefore asking a javascript question.

Comment: Oh then am i supposed to use a submit button to retrieve the selected value from dropdown?

Comment: Either that, or by doing the work on the client-side and sending it to the server-side using something other than a form submit.

Comment: Even though you are using Perl to generate the HTML, this is more a JavaScript question than a Perl question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: WITH ONCHANGE**

Ok to get your value from a combo box use javascript

```
   function getCombo1(sel) {
       var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
   }
   <select id="combo1" onchange="getCombo1(this)">
   <option value="">Select combo</option>
   <option value="Value1">Text1</option>
   <option value="Value2">Text2</option>
   <option value="Value3">Text3</option>
   </select>
```

Now every time a user selects or changes the value of the combo box, a function named 'sel' will be called to update the variable that stores this value.

Hope this helps you.
Let me know if it does.

**PK**

Comment: Thanks for the reply,But its still not working.I hope it works for Onchange event but i have no idea how to retrieve using that event.Please do help me out. Thank you

Comment: ive made adjustments to the answer please have a look. this is definitely what you are look for.

Answer (score 1):

As rafl said in his comment, Perl does not have DOM events. You'd have to go through [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) in order to respond to this event without changing the page.

Here's how it goes: Perl creates *text* that gets interpreted by your browser according to the standards as they identify themselves. Since, your browser expects the base context to be an SGML/HTML document it interprets the SGML/HTML tags as document information and layout instructions. When it comes to a `<script>` tag, if the script identifies itself as JavaScript (or does not specify the language), the browser interprets *text* inside that tag as JavaScript and performs the actions specified.

Perl creates the *text*, only client-side script runs on your browser, completely independent from the Perl that created the text. You can communicate back to the server through forms and cookies (actually part of the HTTP protocol--the *actual* base context of the communication), but there has to be another request to the server. The only thing that can tell a browser what to do in response to interaction with the browser is client-side code executed by the browser.

In order to create a web application Perl (or any other server-side language) just has to create text that uses the browser capabilities to send data back to the server, so that the server-side process can read the state and generated new text that replicates the interaction.

The current way of doing this dynamically, without changing the page is through [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp), which is basically offers the JavaScript an object to make server requests. (The idea is not totally new, we used to accomplish similar things in Java Applets, it's just that Ajax cuts out a middle man.) A good toolkit for JavaScript/Ajax is the [prototype library](http://api.prototypejs.org/).